# MODX Rev: Retrieving Images from a TV

Tags: php, html, image, modx

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a template variable. However I'm trying to pull the image on a blog template. Whenever I go down one level it works without a problem. I've tried using GetResources and GetResourceField to get the image on the top level but so far no results. Here's my code, any suggestions would be great.

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`[[*articleImage]]` &isTV=`1` &processTV=`1`]]

[[*articleImage:phpthumbof=`w=120&h=120`]] 

          [[!getResources?
              &showHidden=`1`
              &limit=`4`
              &includeContent=`1`
              &includeTVs=`1` 
              &processTVs=`1`
          ]]
```

Comment: Alright so I added &tpl=`imgBlog` so the results are being outputted to the chunk. However the chunk still fails to retrieve the image path. The GetResources seem to work though. Any help?

Comment: Alright problem solved, this is the code used: 

Template:

              [[!getResources?
                  &showHidden=`1`
                  &tpl=`imgBlog`
                  &limit=`4`
                  &includeContent=`1`
                  &includeTVs=`1`  
                  &tvPrefix=`tv.`                       
              ]]

The chunk: 
<img src="[[+tv.articleImage]]" alt="Hoi" />

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access your image in your imgBlog chunk, if you are using getGresources you should be using:

```
[[*tv.articleImage:phpthumbof=`w=120&h=120`]]
```